# python - Control the mouse in linux without gui

Tags: python, linux, mouse, centos8

I want to control the mouse in linux without gui.

For example, I want to click by moving the mouse to the position(x,y) in a specific program.

I tried using mouse, pynput, ctypes, pyautogui of the python library, but it does not work because there is no display.

I hope anyone can find the problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: If there is no GUI and no windows being displayed, what is the point of controlling the mouse? Sounds a bit like a [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: For example, I have a program with only 4 buttons. 
Take a screenshot of the program and upload it by adding the image to flask.
When the user clicks one of the buttons in the image on the web, flask receives the position(x,y) and clicks the position(x,y) in the program.

For example, 4 buttons, in reality it can be very many.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses) is what you want.